# How to stretch all UV faces to fill canvas?

Tags: uv, unity

I need every face of my model to fill the UV canvas (overlap). I thought that Lightmap Unwrap did this but I must be mis-remembering something. I have all edges marked as seams. The mesh is just a subdivided, elongated cube. All but 8 faces are identical and I can tweak those myself. How is this done?

More info: I am making a pallet rack (for a warehouse) and I need the supports to have the same shapes cut out of them at regular intervals. The material is otherwise matte. So I figured I would make a really small, b/w alpha texture and overlay the uv faces so they all fill this small texture space.

Here is the mapping I already did for the upright frames. I have secondary texture coordinates for the lighting to baked later. This will be exported to Unity.
[image]

Here is the horizontal frame that I still need to get the coordinates correct for. I want all these faces to cover the same area, the entire UV space:
[image]

Comment: Hello :). I'm sure you tried *UV > Reset*. Is there a reason why that wouldn't be suitable here?

Comment: Ugh...I missed it. Thank you